# need some str.indexOf assistance javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I don't understand this at all, can someone please explain how `s` has a value?

```
var str="Hello World"

// What is the value of s after each line is executed?

s = str.indexOf("o");

s = str.indexOf("w");

s = str.indexOf("r");

s = str.lastIndexOf("l");
```

Comment: *"can someone please explain how s has a value"* Well, `indexOf()` returns a value and you are assigning that value to `s`. That's why/how "`s` has a value".

Comment: I've answered your question below, but you should really put at least *some* effort into figuring simple things like this out yourself

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply,

> The `indexOf()` method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.

So when we do something like this:

```
s = str.indexOf("o");
```

We are finding the index of `o` within `str` and assigning that value back into `s`.

You can (and should) [read more about the function here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp).

Answer (score 1):

A string is basically an array of characters, so when you say

```
str = "Hello World"
```

The indexOf function treats it as

```
[ "H", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "W", "o", "r", "l", "d"]
   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
```

So if you say `str.indexOf('e')` you will get the index of the first `e` which is 1.

If the letter you are looking for does not exist, the function will return -1.

Comment: Thanks, i was just confused because my answer sheet said that "w" was valued as -1, i guess its just a mistake in the answers then.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between uppercase and lowercase letters

Comment: @spoofskay, if you got answered, then please accept that too.

Answer (score 1):

```
//The 'indexOf()' method returns an integer value that states the position (startig from 0) of the first occurrence of the value of the parameter passed.

//Now, 

var str="Hello World"

s = str.indexOf("o");
console.log(s);
/* This would give an output 4. As you can see, 'o' is the fifth character in the String. If you start from 0, the position is 4. */

s = str.indexOf("w");
console.log(s);
/* This would give an output -1. As you can see 'w' doesn't exist in str. If the required value is not found, the function returns -1. */

s = str.indexOf("r");
console.log(s);
/* This would give an output 8. Why? Refer to the explanation for the first function. */

s = str.lastIndexOf("l");
console.log(s);
/* This would give an output 9. This gives the position of the last occurence of the value of parameter passed. */

/* How s has a value? Because the function returns a value that is assigned to s by '=' operator. */
```